# how to schedule full month, year using extjs4 calendar

Tags: extjs4, extjs-mvc

forum member

I need some help and guidance from you in making an application . **Using which an admin can schedule full month or full year, like the no of working days in a month also how many holidays are there in a month.**

And when the user log-in to add its attendance, when he clicks the calendar to select the day for which he is adding attendance, **the calendar should show the days marked as holiday by admin as disabled. So the user won't be add the attendance for those days.**

Based on the attendance I am going to count the no of hours worked by the user and using it his payroll will be calculated.

I googled and found something like the below link I can use in my application, but is there any other simple and more user friendly things I can use to make it work

http://ext.ensible.com/deploy/dev/examples/calendar/window.html

Comment: Hi, did you find how to that? I have to create a Vacations Module and I think I will have implemente something like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following config properties for Ext.form.field.Date:

```
disabledDays
disabledDaysText
disabledDates
disabledDatesText
```

Comment: not this I just want your suggestion is there any other calendar control I can use to schedule it whole month ex: no of holidays in a month , working days etc.